# Draw on HTML5 Canvas using a mouse

Tags: html, canvas, gesture, gesture-recognition

I want to draw on a HTML Canvas using a mouse (for example, draw a signature, draw a name, ...)

How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: check this!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814442/drawing-a-circle-on-the-canvas-using-mouse-events

Comment: Related to [javascript library for free form drawing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6770899/562769)

Comment: See also: [How do I hand draw on canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22891827/562769)

Comment: A related question: After you draw on a canvas, how to store and post the mouse positions to a server to record (re-trace) the drawing?

Answer (score 314, accepted):

Here is a working sample.

```html
 <html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "black",
        y = 2;
    
    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;
    
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
    }
    
    function color(obj) {
        switch (obj.id) {
            case "green":
                x = "green";
                break;
            case "blue":
                x = "blue";
                break;
            case "red":
                x = "red";
                break;
            case "yellow":
                x = "yellow";
                break;
            case "orange":
                x = "orange";
                break;
            case "black":
                x = "black";
                break;
            case "white":
                x = "white";
                break;
        }
        if (x == "white") y = 14;
        else y = 2;
    
    }
    
    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    
    function erase() {
        var m = confirm("Want to clear");
        if (m) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    
    function save() {
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
    }
    
    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    
            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    <body onload="init()">
        <canvas id="can" width="400" height="400" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;"></canvas>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:12%;left:43%;">Choose Color</div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:45%;width:10px;height:10px;background:green;" id="green" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:46%;width:10px;height:10px;background:blue;" id="blue" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:47%;width:10px;height:10px;background:red;" id="red" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:45%;width:10px;height:10px;background:yellow;" id="yellow" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:46%;width:10px;height:10px;background:orange;" id="orange" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:47%;width:10px;height:10px;background:black;" id="black" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:43%;">Eraser</div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:22%;left:45%;width:15px;height:15px;background:white;border:2px solid;" id="white" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <img id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:52%;" style="display:none;">
        <input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:10%;">
        <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:15%;">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why do you do switch? You can also do x = obj.id. Done.

Comment: I'm trying to use this code, but have issues with the drawing being off vertically when I'm not scrolled all the way down on the page.  What should I change in this code?

Comment: I know its a bit late, but I've tried this in Safari for the iPad and it does not work. Any fix for this?

Comment: @masmrdrr I believe it is because it uses mouse events, which do not work well with touch devices.

Comment: seems variable `dot_flag` is not needed? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @CameronDarlington See this question for a few quality ways of grabbing the mouse position: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas
I had the same problem.

Comment: @Gnijuohz the dot_flag is used to create the initial drawing. It's not necessary, but your drawing will always be off from where you click if you don't use it, so it's a bit inaccurate

Comment: great resource but it doesn't consider the scroll effect for mouse x and y

Comment: I changed `canvas.offsetLeft;` and `canvas.offsetTop;` with `canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;` and `canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;` respectively to fix the scrolling problem.

Comment: This code got me started on the right path. But i have to say that this code is pretty rough and ugly. For anyone finding this and struggling with mouse position, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130415/5552144

Comment: Does not work on a touch screen. Not referring to tablets. I mean a Windows 10 laptop with both a mouse and a touch screen.

Comment: to get this to work with a drawing pen(like a graphics tablet) the mouse events have to be replaced with touch events eg. `touchmove`, `touchstart`, `touchend` and then the `clientX` comes from `e.touches["0"].clientX` in the `findxy()` code, haven't thought of an easy way to detect what's being used though, as you can't listen to both events at the same time from what I've tested. I left `mouseout` as is. It's not perfect, but it does work

Comment: working on this again, wanted to point out if your position is offset the places to edit are in findxy specifically the currX, currY for down/move. add or subtract there till it's right

Comment: For odd `context.lineWidth` (e.g. `1`, `3`) you should add `0.5` to both `prevX/Y` and `currX/Y`, otherwise the line will not be clear - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530593/html5-canvas-and-line-width/7531540#7531540

Answer (score 89):

I think, other examples here are too complicated. This one is simpler and JS only...

```js
// create canvas element and append it to document body
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// some hotfixes... ( ≖_≖)
document.body.style.margin = 0;
canvas.style.position = 'fixed';

// get canvas 2D context and set him correct size
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
resize();

// last known position
var pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', setPosition);

// new position from mouse event
function setPosition(e) {
  pos.x = e.clientX;
  pos.y = e.clientY;
}

// resize canvas
function resize() {
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function draw(e) {
  // mouse left button must be pressed
  if (e.buttons !== 1) return;

  ctx.beginPath(); // begin

  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#c0392b';

  ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y); // from
  setPosition(e);
  ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y); // to

  ctx.stroke(); // draw it!
}
```

Comment: How do I get it to paint on mouse move, not by clicking?

Comment: @RyanCameron.Me just comment line `if (e.buttons !== 1) return;` ;-).

Comment: I got it working on my footer but now the line is about 10px away from my cursor

Comment: If my cursor is in the middle of the canvas it lines up perfectly with the line but if I move the cursor up or down, the line moves further away from the cursor. Any ideas?

Comment: @RyanCameron.Me Just tried newest Chrome, Firefox and Edge and everything working... What browser do you use?

Comment: I think it's because I made the canvas relative. Please scroll to the footer on this page to see what I am talking about: http://weight.ryancameron.me/

Comment: @RyanCameron.Me It's more likely because my `resize` function. I'm setting width and height of canvas based on window size. You should set these based on your `<div class="container-fluid">`.

Comment: that helped with also subtracting about 250 from the y coordinate on the set position function. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: this will only work if the canvas is the full width and height of the window

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach yep, if canvas is not placed in top right corner, you will need to add some `offset` in `setPosition` function...

Comment: What is resize() for? Why do you need to resize the canvas? It can be fixed in width and height.

Comment: @Timo Yep, you can have canvas with fixed width and height, but I choose version where canvas cover entire page. It did not add much complexity, but looks better for this demo :-).

Comment: This is great but makes assumptions about canvas positioning. More generic:        
`var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
pos.x = e.clientX - rect.left;
pos.y = e.clientY - rect.top;`

Answer (score 48):

Here's the most straightforward way to create a drawing application with canvas:

1. Attach a `mousedown`, `mousemove`, and `mouseup` event listener to the canvas DOM
2. on `mousedown`, get the mouse coordinates, and use the `moveTo()` method to position your drawing cursor and the `beginPath()` method to begin a new drawing path.
3. on `mousemove`, continuously add a new point to the path with `lineTo()`, and color the last segment with `stroke()`.
4. on `mouseup`, set a flag to disable the drawing.

From there, you can add all kinds of other features like giving the user the ability to choose a line thickness, color, brush strokes, and even layers.

Comment: If there is beginPath, should there be closePath after mouseup?

Comment: @Timo When you `stroke()`, it autmatically closes the path.

Answer (score 13):

I was looking to use this method for signatures as well, i found a sample on [http://codetheory.in/](http://codetheory.in/html5-canvas-drawing-lines-with-smooth-edges/).

I've added the below code to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3xDg/)

Html:

```
<div id="sketch">
    <canvas id="paint"></canvas>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 (function() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#paint');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
    var sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
    canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
    canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));

    var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
    var last_mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

    /* Mouse Capturing Work */
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
        last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

        mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    }, false);


    /* Drawing on Paint App */
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
    }, false);

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
    }, false);

    var onPaint = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(last_mouse.x, last_mouse.y);
        ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    };

}());
```

Comment: The best part is you can draw straight connected lines by right clicking at different locations. :)

Comment: Does not work on a touch screen. Not referring to tablets. I mean a Windows 10 laptop with both a mouse and a touch screen.

Comment: I get: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Answer (score 7):

I had to provide a simple example for this subject so I'll share here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Haelle/v6tfp2e1

```js
class SignTool {
  constructor() {
    this.initVars()
    this.initEvents()
  }

  initVars() {
    this.canvas = $('#canvas')[0]
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d")
    this.isMouseClicked = false
    this.isMouseInCanvas = false
    this.prevX = 0
    this.currX = 0
    this.prevY = 0
    this.currY = 0
  }

  initEvents() {
    $('#canvas').on("mousemove", (e) => this.onMouseMove(e))
    $('#canvas').on("mousedown", (e) => this.onMouseDown(e))
    $('#canvas').on("mouseup", () => this.onMouseUp())
    $('#canvas').on("mouseout", () => this.onMouseOut())
    $('#canvas').on("mouseenter", (e) => this.onMouseEnter(e))
  }
  
  onMouseDown(e) {
   this.isMouseClicked = true
    this.updateCurrentPosition(e)
  }
  
  onMouseUp() {
   this.isMouseClicked = false
  }
  
  onMouseEnter(e) {
   this.isMouseInCanvas = true
    this.updateCurrentPosition(e)
  }
  
  onMouseOut() {
   this.isMouseInCanvas = false
  }

  onMouseMove(e) {
    if (this.isMouseClicked && this.isMouseInCanvas) {
     this.updateCurrentPosition(e)
      this.draw()
    }
  }
  
  updateCurrentPosition(e) {
      this.prevX = this.currX
      this.prevY = this.currY
      this.currX = e.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft
      this.currY = e.clientY - this.canvas.offsetTop
  }
  
  draw() {
    this.ctx.beginPath()
    this.ctx.moveTo(this.prevX, this.prevY)
    this.ctx.lineTo(this.currX, this.currY)
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = "black"
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 2
    this.ctx.stroke()
    this.ctx.closePath()
  }
}

var canvas = new SignTool()
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is a wonderful example and simple to understand in a class !!! I converted it to vanilla JavaScript to avoid loading extra crappy  jquery ! Thank you !!!!!

Answer (score 6):

Here is my very simple working canvas draw and erase.

https://jsfiddle.net/richardcwc/d2gxjdva/

```js
//Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Variables
var canvasx = $(canvas).offset().left;
var canvasy = $(canvas).offset().top;
var last_mousex = last_mousey = 0;
var mousex = mousey = 0;
var mousedown = false;
var tooltype = 'draw';

//Mousedown
$(canvas).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    last_mousex = mousex = parseInt(e.clientX-canvasx);
 last_mousey = mousey = parseInt(e.clientY-canvasy);
    mousedown = true;
});

//Mouseup
$(canvas).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    mousedown = false;
});

//Mousemove
$(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    mousex = parseInt(e.clientX-canvasx);
    mousey = parseInt(e.clientY-canvasy);
    if(mousedown) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        if(tooltype=='draw') {
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        } else {
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
            ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        }
        ctx.moveTo(last_mousex,last_mousey);
        ctx.lineTo(mousex,mousey);
        ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    last_mousex = mousex;
    last_mousey = mousey;
    //Output
    $('#output').html('current: '+mousex+', '+mousey+'<br/>last: '+last_mousex+', '+last_mousey+'<br/>mousedown: '+mousedown);
});

//Use draw|erase
use_tool = function(tool) {
    tooltype = tool; //update
}
```

```css
canvas {
    cursor: crosshair;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
<input type="button" value="draw" onclick="use_tool('draw');" />
<input type="button" value="erase" onclick="use_tool('erase');" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

A super short version, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GA0I90OAGXLO), without `position:absolute` in vanilla JavaScript. The main idea is to move the canvas' context to the right coordinates and draw a line. Uncomment `click` handler and comment `mousedown` & `mousemove` handlers below to get a feel for how it is working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p style="margin: 50px">Just some padding in y direction</p>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="background: #000; margin-left: 100px;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
    const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    // c.addEventListener("click", penTool); // fires after mouse left btn is released
    c.addEventListener("mousedown", setLastCoords); // fires before mouse left btn is released
    c.addEventListener("mousemove", freeForm);


    const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    function setLastCoords(e) {
        const {x, y} = c.getBoundingClientRect();
        lastX = e.clientX - x;
        lastY = e.clientY - y;
    }

    function freeForm(e) {
        if (e.buttons !== 1) return; // left button is not pushed yet
        penTool(e);
    }

    function penTool(e) {
        const {x, y} = c.getBoundingClientRect();
        const newX = e.clientX - x;
        const newY = e.clientY - y;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(newX, newY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

        lastX = newX;
        lastY = newY;
    }

    let lastX = 0;
    let lastY = 0;  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is important, not to set the width and height in CSS as it only stretches the canvas instead of resizing it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8693791/1585523

Answer (score 3):

Also check this one here:
Example:
https://github.com/williammalone/Simple-HTML5-Drawing-App

Documentation:
http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/

This document includes following codes:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="490" height="220"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");

$('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
  var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        
  paint = true;
  addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
  redraw();
});

$('#canvas').mouseup(function(e){
  paint = false;
});

$('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e){
  paint = false;
});

var clickX = new Array();
var clickY = new Array();
var clickDrag = new Array();
var paint;

function addClick(x, y, dragging)
{
  clickX.push(x);
  clickY.push(y);
  clickDrag.push(dragging);
}

//Also redraw
function redraw(){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas
  
  context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
  context.lineJoin = "round";
  context.lineWidth = 5;
            
  for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++) {        
    context.beginPath();
    if(clickDrag[i] && i){
      context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
     }else{
       context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
     }
     context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
     context.closePath();
     context.stroke();
  }
}
```

And another awesome example
http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/

Answer (score 3):

It's been years since the question was asked and was answered.

For anyone who looks for a simple drawing canvas (eg, for taking the signature from the user/customer), here I am posting a more simplified jquery version of the currently accepted answer

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var flag, dot_flag = false,
 prevX, prevY, currX, currY = 0,
 color = 'black', thickness = 2;
  var $canvas = $('#canvas');
  var ctx = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');

  $canvas.on('mousemove mousedown mouseup mouseout', function(e) {
    prevX = currX;
    prevY = currY;
    currX = e.clientX - $canvas.offset().left;
    currY = e.clientY - $canvas.offset().top;
    if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
      flag = true;
    }
    if (e.type == 'mouseup' || e.type == 'mouseout') {
      flag = false;
    }
    if (e.type == 'mousemove') {
      if (flag) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.lineWidth = thickness;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  });

  $('.canvas-clear').on('click', function(e) {
    c_width = $canvas.width();
    c_height = $canvas.height();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c_width, c_height);
    $('#canvasimg').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;"></canvas>
    <input type="button" value="Clear" class="canvas-clear" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I took the first answer and Changed as per my need.
Now

1. Works on mobile device also.
2. more responsive,
3. no issue with scroll

```html
 <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .selected::before {

           content: 'x';
           height: 30px;
           width: 30px;
           left: 18px;
           top: -8px;
           font-size: 3rem;
           position: absolute;
        }

        .select-colour{
          height: 30px;
          width: 30px;
        }

    </style>
 </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "black",
        y = 2;
    
    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;
    
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e, '')
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e, '')
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e, '')
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e, '')
        }, false);

        canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e, 'touch')
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e, 'touch')
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e, 'touch')
        }, false);    

    }
    
    function color(obj) {        
        x = obj.id; 
        if (x == "white") y = 14;
        else y = 2;
        var prevSelected = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
        // If it exists, remove it.
        if(prevSelected.length > 0) { 
          prevSelected[0].classList.remove("selected");
        }
                 
       document.getElementById(obj.id).classList.add("selected");
    }
    
    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    
    function erase() {
        var m = confirm("Want to clear");
        if (m) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    
    function save() {
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
    }

    function download() {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        link.href = dataURL;
        link.download = 'mydrawing.png';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
    
    function findxy(res, e, source) {
        if(source){
            var clientX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
            var clientY = e.changedTouches[0].clientY;
        }else{
            var clientX = e.clientX;
            var clientY = e.clientY;
        }

        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            currY = clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    
            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }

        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }

        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                currY = clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
  <body onload="init()">
        <div style="">
                <div style="float: left;">
                   <canvas id="can" width="600" height="500" style=" border:5px solid;"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left:20px; float:left;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">Choose Color</div>
                        <div class="col-2 pt-3"><div class="select-colour" style="background:green;" id="green" onclick="color(this)"></div></div>
                       <div class="col-2 pt-3"><div class="select-colour" style="background:blue;" id="blue" onclick="color(this)"></div></div>
                       <div class="col-2 pt-3"><div class="select-colour" style="background:red;" id="red" onclick="color(this)"></div></div>
                       <div class="col-2 pt-3"><div class="select-colour" style="background:yellow;" id="yellow" onclick="color(this)"></div></div>
                       <div class="col-2 pt-3"><div class="select-colour" style="background:orange;" id="orange" onclick="color(this)"></div></div>
                       <div class="col-2 pt-3"><div class="select-colour" style="background:black;" id="black" onclick="color(this)"></div></div>
                       <div class="col-12 pt-3 pb-3" style="">Eraser</div>
                       <div class="col-2 pt-3"><div class="select-colour" style="background:white;border:2px solid;" id="white" onclick="color(this)"></div></div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 col-lg-12 mt-3">
                        <input type="button" value="Download" id="download" size="23" onclick="download()" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-lg-12 mt-3">
                            <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" class="btn btn-light">
                    </div>          
                </div>
           </div>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used what 1083202 did but removed all the controlles, and implemented the change that KWILLIAMS suggested, that made it non sensitive to scrolling. I also made the canvas big, basically over my whole page 2000x1600 px, excepts for the margins. I did remove all the drawing tools and buttons, and used "blue" as the only color.

I put the JS-code in a separate file named myJS.js, and put that in a folder named "JS" localy:

I then used a Stylus on my Laptop to write on the tuchpad, witch works out a bit better then with the finger or mouse.

The document I use it for is kind of informal, for internal use, but it is nice to be able to put some pen strokes on it before making a pdf-file.

```js
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "blue",
        y = 3;
    
    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;
    
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
    }
 
    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
   
    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    
            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<html> 



<body onload="init()">
<p>Below you can draw:</p>
<canvas id="can" width="750" height="1050" style="position:absolute;">Below you can write:</canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if you have trouble implementing this. It uses processing.js and has features for changing colors and making the draw point larger and smaller.

```
<html>
<head>
<!--script librarires-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="processing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="init.js"></script>

<!--styles -->
<style type="text/css" src="stylesheet.css">
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<!--toolbox -->
<div id="draggable toolbox"></div>
<script type="application/processing">
// new script
int prevx, prevy;
int newx, newy;
boolean cliked;
color c1 = #000000;
int largeur=2;
int ps = 20;
int px = 50;
int py = 50;

void setup() {
size(500,500);
frameRate(25);
background(50);

 prevx = mouseX;
 prevy = mouseY;
 cliked = false;
 }

void draw() {
 //couleur
 noStroke(0);
 fill(#FFFFFF);//blanc
rect(px, py, ps, ps);
 fill(#000000);
 rect(px, py+(ps), ps, ps);
 fill(#FF0000);
 rect(px, py+(ps*2), ps, ps);
 fill(#00FF00);
 rect(px, py+(ps*3), ps, ps);
 fill(#FFFF00);
 rect(px, py+(ps*4), ps, ps);
 fill(#0000FF);
 rect(px, py+(ps*5), ps, ps);
 //largeur
 fill(#FFFFFF);
 rect(px, py+(ps*7), ps, ps);
  fill(#FFFFFF);
 rect(px, py+(ps*8), ps, ps);
 stroke(#000000);
 line(px+2, py+(ps*7)+(ps/2), px+(ps-2), py+(ps*7)+(ps/2));
 line(px+(ps/2), py+(ps*7)+1, px+(ps/2), py+(ps*8)-1);
 line(px+2, py+(ps*8)+(ps/2), px+(ps-2), py+(ps*8)+(ps/2));

 if(cliked==false){
  prevx = mouseX;
 prevy = mouseY;  
 }
 if(mousePressed) { 
  cliked = true;
 newx = mouseX;
  newy = mouseY;
  strokeWeight(largeur);
  stroke(c1);
  line(prevx, prevy, newx, newy);
  prevx = newx;
 prevy = newy;
 }else{
  cliked= false;
  }
}
void mouseClicked() {
 if (mouseX>=px && mouseX<=(px+ps)){
  //couleur
  if (mouseY>=py && mouseY<=py+(ps*6)){ 
   c1 = get(mouseX, mouseY);
  }
   //largeur
  if (mouseY>=py+(ps*7) && mouseY<=py+(ps*8)){ 
   largeur += 2;
  }
 if (mouseY>=py+(ps*8) && mouseY<=py+(ps*9)){ 
   if (largeur>2){
    largeur -= 2;
   }
  }
 }
}
</script><canvas></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't understand it, but it starts processing.

Answer (score 1):

if you have background image for your canvas, you will have to make some tweaks to have it work properly because white erasing trick will hide the background.

here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/MohammedEssehemy/7773042b6e14d772f3ca567dfee08f5f) with the code.

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas, canvasimg, backgroundImage, finalImg;
    var mouseClicked = false;
    var prevX = 0;
    var currX = 0;
    var prevY = 0;
    var currY = 0;
    var fillStyle = "black";
    var globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    var lineWidth = 2;

    function init() {
      var imageSrc = '/abstract-geometric-pattern_23-2147508597.jpg'
      backgroundImage = new Image();
      backgroundImage.src = imageSrc;
      canvas = document.getElementById('can');
      finalImg = document.getElementById('finalImg');
      canvasimg = document.getElementById('canvasimg');
      canvas.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imageSrc + "')";
      canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseEvent);
      canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseEvent);
      canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseEvent);
      canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseEvent);
    }

    function getColor(btn) {
      globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
      lineWidth = 2;
      switch (btn.getAttribute('data-color')) {
        case "green":
        fillStyle = "green";
        break;
        case "blue":
        fillStyle = "blue";
        break;
        case "red":
        fillStyle = "red";
        break;
        case "yellow":
        fillStyle = "yellow";
        break;
        case "orange":
        fillStyle = "orange";
        break;
        case "black":
        fillStyle = "black";
        break;
        case "eraser":
        globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
        fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
        lineWidth = 14;
        break;
      }

    }

    function draw(dot) {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = globalCompositeOperation;
      if(dot){
        ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
        ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
      } else {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = fillStyle;
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        ctx.stroke();
      }
      ctx.closePath();
    }

    function erase() {
      if (confirm("Want to clear")) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
      }
    }

    function save() {
      canvas.style.border = "2px solid";
      canvasimg.width = canvas.width;
      canvasimg.height = canvas.height;
      var ctx2 = canvasimg.getContext("2d");
      // comment next line to save the draw only
      ctx2.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
      ctx2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
      finalImg.src = canvasimg.toDataURL();
      finalImg.style.display = "inline";
    }

    function handleMouseEvent(e) {
      if (e.type === 'mousedown') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.offsetX;
        currY = e.offsetY;
        mouseClicked = true;
        draw(true);
      }
      if (e.type === 'mouseup' || e.type === "mouseout") {
        mouseClicked = false;
      }
      if (e.type === 'mousemove') {
        if (mouseClicked) {
          prevX = currX;
          prevY = currY;
          currX = e.offsetX;
          currY = e.offsetY;
          draw();
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
    <body onload="init()">
      <canvas id="can" width="400" height="400" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;">
      </canvas>
      <div style="position:absolute;top:12%;left:43%;">Choose Color</div>
      <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:45%;width:10px;height:10px;background:green;" data-color="green" onclick="getColor(this)"></div>
      <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:46%;width:10px;height:10px;background:blue;" data-color="blue" onclick="getColor(this)"></div>
      <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:47%;width:10px;height:10px;background:red;" data-color="red" onclick="getColor(this)"></div>
      <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:45%;width:10px;height:10px;background:yellow;" data-color="yellow" onclick="getColor(this)"></div>
      <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:46%;width:10px;height:10px;background:orange;" data-color="orange" onclick="getColor(this)"></div>
      <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:47%;width:10px;height:10px;background:black;" data-color="black" onclick="getColor(this)"></div>
      <div style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:43%;">Eraser</div>
      <div style="position:absolute;top:22%;left:45%;width:15px;height:15px;background:white;border:2px solid;" data-color="eraser" onclick="getColor(this)"></div>
      <canvas id="canvasimg" style="display:none;" ></canvas>
      <img id="finalImg" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:52%;display:none;" >
      <input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:10%;">
      <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:15%;">
    </body>
    </html>
```