# Drawing a circle on the canvas using mouse events

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry

I am trying to draw a circle using mouse on the canvas using mouse events, but it does not draw anything:

```
tools.circle = function () {
var tool = this;
this.started = false;
this.mousedown = function (ev) {
tool.started = true;
tool.x0 = ev._x;
tool.y0 = ev._y;
ctx.moveTo(tool.x0,tool.y0);
};

this.mousemove = function (ev) {
var centerX = Math.max(tool.x0,ev._x) - Math.abs(tool.x0 - ev._x)/2;
var centerY = Math.max(tool.y0,ev._y) - Math.abs(tool.y0 - ev._y)/2;
var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(tool.x0 - ev._x,2) + Math.pow(tool.y0 - ev._y));
context.circle(tool.x0, tool.y0, distance/2,0,Math.PI*2 ,true);
context.stroke();
};
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this code snippet doesn't tell us much, but there are a couple of obvious errors in your code.
First, DOM Event object doesn't have _`x` and _`y` properties. but rather `clientX` and `clientY` or `pageX` and `pageY`.
To get relative mouse coordinates from the current event object, you would do something like:

```
element.onclick = function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
}
```

Next, canvas' 2d context doesn't have a method called `circle`, but you could write your own, maybe something like:

```
var ctx = canvas.context;
ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
    this.fillStyle = fillColor;
    this.beginPath();
    this.moveTo(x, y);
    this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    this.fill();
}
```

Anyhow, here's a test html page to test this out: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/kneDX/

I hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: not exactly as i wanted but did helped me to understand how to implement exactly what i wanted to do using mouse events for circle

Comment: Can you share the list of mouse events like in jSFiddele, we have onmouseover event,  do we have list of other event somewhere documented ?

Comment: @PKKG Read more about DOM events (including mouse events) here: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mouseevents