# Draw circle over image with mouse like Paint in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Dow we have any Nuget or github, using that we could draw circle over image with the help of mouse like we can do in Paint.

Any link will be ver helpful

Comment: not sure about a github solution

Answer (score 2):

use Canvas in HTML, and java script. below will help:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/html5-drawing-images-and-adding-text-to-the-canvas-element/

drawing circle with mousemove:
[Drawing a circle on the canvas using mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814442/drawing-a-circle-on-the-canvas-using-mouse-events)

Comment: can we draw circle over image using mouse, using the code mentioned in this link.

Comment: Can we save the canvas after set image over it and then drowing done over image ?

Comment: :) My question was: after drawing the circles and drawing over canvas image. can we save the updated canvas image ?

Comment: yes: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/

Answer (score 1):

See the third example here, they are drawing on a cat image:

http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/

Comment: could we use circles as well ?

Comment: You can do circles, but probably requires you do some work to interact with the API and mouse.  At some point the rubber meets the road and you've gotta do some work: http://codepen.io/jackrugile/full/IjKLt