# ruby gem to support drawing

Tags: javascript, html, drawing

Is there a ruby gem which has pens/paint brush and stuff so that one can draw on a site? If not, how can I start developing something like that?

I basically want to create a simple app which lets people draw sketches and stuff online. I'm open to using other frameworks other then rails.

Comment: read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368784/draw-by-mouse-with-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. Ruby is a server side stuff, while drawing is a client side.

You need to search some javascript libraries.