# javascript library for free form drawing

Tags: javascript, html, drawing

Is there a javascript library which lets me draw on a web page and then save the state of that drawing?

I want to draw an 2D image using the mouse and then how to store and load that drawing

Comment: Related: [How do I hand draw on canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22891827/562769)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at [ProcessingJS](http://processingjs.org/).

Comment: does that let me draw dynamically using my mouse? or I need to have pre-defined shapes and it just loads it?

Answer (score 10):

Use HTML5 Canvas. A simple example for drawing images is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ghostoy/wTmFE/1/.

I recommend this online book: [Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/canvas.html).

Comment: The OP wants to actually draw on the page using a pencil, for example, not an image.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the free drawing to work with touchscreens, I recommend Fabric.js:

- [Demo](http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing/)
- [Tutorial](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4/)

### Code:

```
<canvas id="c1" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid black;">
</canvas>

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 5;
console.log(canvas);
```

See [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MartinThoma/B525t/)