# Offset when drawing on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse, draw, html5-canvas

Have a simple drawing application. The problem is in the coordinates (`redraw` function): they must be mouse, but are near 2x mouse. What's the problem in the code?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
body{
    background-color: green;
}

#workspace{
    width: 700px;
    height:420px;
    margin: 40px auto 20px auto;
    border: black dashed 1px;
}

#canvas{
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");
        var clickX = new Array();
        var clickY = new Array();
        var clickDrag = new Array();
        var paint;

        $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
            var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
            paint = true;
            addClick(mouseX,mouseY, false);
            redraw();
        });

        $('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
            if(paint){
                addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
                redraw();
            }
        });

        $('#canvas').mouseup(function(e){
            paint = false;
        });

        $('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e){
            paint = false;
        });

        function addClick(x, y, dragging)
        {
            clickX.push(x);
            clickY.push(y);
            clickDrag.push(dragging);
        }

        function redraw(){
            canvas.width = canvas.width; // Clears the canvas

            context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
            context.lineJoin = "round";
            context.lineWidth = 5;

            for(var i=1; i < clickX.length; i++)
            {
                context.beginPath();
                if(clickDrag[i] && i){
                    context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
                }else{
                    context.moveTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
                }
                context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
                context.closePath();
                context.stroke();
            }

            console.log(clickX[clickX.length-1]+" "+clickY[clickX.length-1]);
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="workspace">
<canvas id="canvas"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should not set a canvas' width/height through CSS. It makes the canvas stretch instead of making the resolution higher. This means that although the coordinates are correct, they will visually end up somewhere else.

For example, an x coordinate of `100` will be stretched to visually be an x coordinate of `200` (or something else; at least it will be bigger than `100` since it's been stretched).

Instead, use:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="420" />
```

and remove the `width: 100%` in CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/euXJC/1/

Comment: remove the `width` in the `css` was the key for me