# Ionic 3 - Canvas draw is not perfect as per mouse/touch position

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-canvas, ionic3, angular6

I have created one app, where user can draw anything on canvas. I have added background image to canvas. I want canvas to cover the remaining space on screen. Hence I kept width and height in percent.

**Issue -**  Now whenever I draw something on canvas, it won't follow accurate position of mouse/touch on screen. If I draw below it will draw near about 20px up from touch. (Not sure about how much pixel up but its my assumption)

Please go-through below code.

**1. HTML**

```
<ion-row>
      <canvas no-bounce 
      (touchstart)='handleStart($event)' (touchmove)='handleMove($event)' (click)="removeSelectedTxt()"
      [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + selectedImage + ') no-repeat center center fixed', '-webkit-background-size': 'contain',
      '-moz-background-size': 'contain',
      '-o-background-size': 'contain',
      'background-size': 'contain',
      'width': '98%',
      'height': '65%'}" #canvas ></canvas>
  </ion-row>
```

**2. CSS**

```
canvas {
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      position: fixed;
      top: 10%;
      left: 1%;
    }
```

**3. TS file**

```
    import { Component, ViewChild,  ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

     @ViewChild('canvas') public canvas: ElementRef;

    this.canvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;

handleStart(ev){

        this.lastX = ev.touches[0].pageX;
        this.lastY = ev.touches[0].pageY;
    }

    handleMove(ev){

      let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
      let currentX = ev.touches[0].pageX;
      let currentY = ev.touches[0].pageY;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineJoin = "round";
      ctx.moveTo(this.lastX, this.lastY);
      ctx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = this.currentColour;
      ctx.lineWidth = this.brushSize;
      ctx.stroke();      

      this.lastX = currentX;
      this.lastY = currentY;
    }
```

Need help, how do I draw the accurate points of touch on canvas?

Comment: Sounds like you have an offset issue... also there are issues with setting the dimensions via css:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693693/offset-when-drawing-on-canvas

Comment: Thanks buddy for your help.. I used mouse event but its not working good with touch events... Even I used same logic for touch event but still same issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing so many exercises and research on canvas draw, finally I resolved the issue.

I did below changes in  typescript file. Calculated `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` in `ionViewDidLoad` method.

**1. ionViewDidLoad() method**

```
this.offsetX = this.canvasElement.offsetLeft;
this.offsetY = this.canvasElement.offsetTop;
```

- Once user starts drawing on canvas, means touchStart event, I called handleStart() method. Here I did changes.

**2. handleStart(event) method**

```
handleStart(ev){

        this.lastX = ev.touches[0].pageX - this.offsetX;
        this.lastY = ev.touches[0].pageY - this.offsetY;
    }
```

- To draw on canvas, I called touchMove event.

**3. handleMove(event) method**

```
handleMove(ev){

      // let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
      let currentX = ev.touches[0].pageX - this.offsetX;
      let currentY = ev.touches[0].pageY - this.offsetY;

      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.lineJoin = "round";
      this.ctx.moveTo(this.lastX, this.lastY);
      this.ctx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
      this.ctx.closePath();
      this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.currentColour;
      this.ctx.lineWidth = this.brushSize;
      this.ctx.stroke();      


      this.undoList.push({
        x_start: currentX,
        y_start: currentY,
        x_end: this.lastX,
        y_end: this.lastY,
        color: this.currentColour,
        size: this.brushSize,
        mode: this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation
      });

      this.lastX = currentX;
      this.lastY = currentY;

    }
```

***Note - If you see closely in code, what I did is I calculated offsetLeft and offsetTop. Then minus this from touch points in both handleStart and handleMove method.***