# C# Allow the user to draw their signature on the form

Tags: c#

I'm building an ibanking system with my friends and I'm in charge for the credits part. I want to allow the user to have their signature on a webform and is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do that in C#, on the web if you want user interactivity like drawing you'll have to do it in javascript (on the browser), the user isn't going to go in your datacenter and draw on the server :)

If you're fine with limiting yourself to HTML 5 browsers you should be able to do this with drawing in a canva and then sending the finished drawing to the server. Here is another SO question that covers user drawing in a canva: [Draw on HTML5 Canvas using a mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368784/draw-on-html5-canvas-using-a-mouse)