# Cursor position not good

Tags: javascript, html, css

I looked for solutions to this problem for a long time, found some and I thought I understand but apparently I don't. I'd like to make a canvas that ppl can use to sign to confirm a booking. But I can't get the line to follow the user's cursor. My code looks like this:
HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Signature Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test.css">
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header id="header">

    </header>

    <section id="content">
        <canvas id="signaturePad">DSorry your browser is rubbish</canvas>
    </section>

    <footer>

    </footer>

    <script src="../js/test.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header 
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

#content
{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#content #signaturePad
{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
}

footer
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

And finally the JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("signaturePad");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = 1;
var dragging = false;
context.lineWidth = 2*radius;

function displayMousePosition(mouseX, mouseY) {
    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    header.innerHTML = "X : " + mouseX + "<br />Y : " + mouseY;
}

function getMousePosition(e) {
    var mouseX = 0,
        mouseY = 0,
        elmX = 0,
        elmY = 0,
        obj = this;
    //get mouse position on document crossbrowser
    if (!e){e = window.event;}
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY){
        mouseX= e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY;
    } else if (e.clientX || e.clientY){
        mouseX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
                 + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        mouseY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
                 + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    //get parent element position in document
    if (obj.offsetParent){
        do{ 
            elmX += obj.offsetLeft;
            elmY += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }

    displayMousePosition(mouseX, mouseY);
    return [mouseX, mouseY];
}

var putPoint = function(e) {
    if(dragging) {
        var offset = $("#signaturePad").offset();
        var mouseX = getMousePosition(e)[0];
        var mouseY = getMousePosition(e)[1];
        context.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        context.stroke();
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        context.fill();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}

$(document).on("mousedown", "#signaturePad", function(e) {
    dragging = true;
    putPoint(e);
});

$(document).on("mouseup", "#signaturePad", function() {
    dragging = false;
    context.beginPath();
});

$(document).on("mousemove", "#signaturePad", function(e) {
    putPoint(e);
});
```

And the fiddle if you wanna see it live: https://jsfiddle.net/Cellendhyll/yxguemf0/7/

Comment: Maybe [THIS QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368784/draw-on-html5-canvas-using-a-mouse) could help you in any way?

Comment: @kevinb. Perfect! Thx a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw on HTML5 Canvas using a mouse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368784/draw-on-html5-canvas-using-a-mouse)