# Is there a way to sketch or mark up a photo and use it in an html form element?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to digitize an order form for a printing company. This form has a section where you make a simple sketch of the product being ordered. I want to integrate this into an html form that will have the output emailed to the correct person. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Edit: Here is an example from jotform: http://form.jotformpro.com/form/52071860014950?

Comment: You mean the user can draw with their mouse and submit the drawing as an image by using a `<form>`?

Comment: @showdev canvas + http POST would do it.

Comment: Exactly. Here is an example I found that Jotform has implemented: http://form.jotformpro.com/form/52071860014950?

Comment: You would use the HTML `<canvas>` element for the user to do the drawing on and then save the drawing as a "data URL". You'd then take that data URL and populate an `<input type=hidden">`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I think that is the right direction. Thanks so much! Is there a fiddle or something that you know of that demonstrates this?

Comment: [Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368784/draw-on-html5-canvas-using-a-mouse) to show how to allow the user to draw on the canvas. Then, when ready, call the [`.toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) canvas method to convert the drawing to a URL. Finally, just set that URL as the `value` of an `input type=hidden` - then it will be submitted along with the rest of the form.