# How to draw shape in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to draw shape in div element. The code below draws a shape in correct starting point if not transform scale. But if transform scale, the line is not in the correct position when drawing the shape. How to fix the code below if the div is transform scale in (0.7, 0.7)? Thank you in advance.

```
$(function() {
    var $container = $('#container');
    var $selection = $('<div>').addClass('selection-box');

    $container.on('mousedown', function(e) {
        var click_y = e.pageY,
        click_x = e.pageX;

        $selection.css({
          'top':    click_y,
          'left':   click_x,
          'width':  0,
          'height': 0
        });
        $selection.appendTo($container);

        $container.on('mousemove', function(e) {            
          var move_x = e.pageX,
              move_y = e.pageY,
              width  = Math.abs(move_x - click_x),
              height = Math.abs(move_y - click_y),
              new_x, new_y;

          new_x = (move_x < click_x) ? (click_x - width) : click_x;
          new_y = (move_y < click_y) ? (click_y - height) : click_y;

          $selection.css({
            'width': width,
            'height': height,
            'top': new_y,
            'left': new_x
          });

        }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
            $container.off('mousemove');
            $selection.remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: please provide specific information and demo of code

Comment: This is the demo https://jsbin.com/ireqix/226/edit?html,js,output

Comment: what you want to draw in this #container?

Comment: yes. the code above works if the container is not transform scale, but if transform scale, the drawing of shape line is not correct.

Comment: please check this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/8398189/6923146

Comment: that doesn't answer my question.